# Coefficient of Determination: For the perimeter and area of a square: Why different?

Tags: linear-model, regression-coefficients

When calculating the coefficient of determination for a square, why is it that if you use the data set for the side length of as X= (1,2,3,4) and the perimeter as Y=(4,8,12,16) the Coefficient of Determination equals 100%.

But when doing the same calculation for using the area of the square with the X points (1,2,3,4) and the Y data point (1,4,9,16) the Coeff of Determ decreases to 96%?

Any insight would be great.  The simpler the language the better too.  Thanks!!

Comment: This reads like very slightly reworded bookwork. Is this a question for some subject? Please also try to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 2):

In a linear regression, the [coefficient of determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination):

> ... indicates how well data points fit a statistical model

... which in the case of linear regression is a line. i.e. "How well does a line fit?"

Consider: the [coefficient of determination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_squared_correlation_coefficient), $R^2$ is the square of $r$ (*), the Pearson correlation between $y$ and $x$:

> ... in linear least squares regression with an estimated intercept term, $R^2$ equals the square of the Pearson correlation coefficient between the observed and modeled (predicted) data values of the dependent variable.

*  (the change in case is deliberate)

In turn [the correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) measures *linear* association:

> In statistics, the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient [...] is a measure of the ***linear*** correlation (dependence) between two variables $X$ and $Y$,

---

With those facts in mind:

(i) draw a plot of the *perimeter* against side length for your data

(ii) draw a plot of the *area* against side length for your data

-- what do you notice?

Comment: great explanation, very clear now.  I should of just plotted it immediately. Thanks for the help!